# How to emulate a "Paste" in Selenium IDE add-on for Firefox?

Tags: facebook, selenium, firefox, ide

With the help of the Selenium IDE add-on for Firefox, I'm trying to publish a post on Facebook that will include a link, the post should also contain the usual 'link preview' (image and/or description text) scraped from the website I'm sharing.

For this purpose I played around with the following commands to no avail: "type" ; "typeKeys" ; "SendKeys"... the result was actually expected because these commands mimic typing, and if you manually write a link (by typing it) while trying to publish a post on Facebook - the "link preview" (image and/or description) won't be loaded.  I also tried to emulate pressing "ctrl + [a/c/v]" in 3 separate commands as a workaround after the link as a text was written in the 'update your status' field, but no luck with those. See the visual examples below:

Selenium IDE contains:

```
Store | https://9gag.com/ | link
[[bunch of irrelevant commands in-between]]
typeKeys | class=_1mf _1mj | ${link}
```

Result:
[Screenshot 1 - imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHY36.png)

If you publish the post this way, it'll end up like a plain text. Not a valid share. The thing I'm trying to achieve with Selenium IDE is what's shown on the screenshot below. You can achieve it by copying some absolute URL and pasting it (**ctrl + v**) inside the 'update your status' window on Facebook.

Result:
[Screenshot 2- imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1jXF.png)

**Important:** Workarounds are welcome as always, but here's what's not welcome as a workaround from other off-topic non-Selenium related reasons:

1. Using this sharing form: facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[absolute URL you want to share]
2. Using the mobile/touch version of Facebook

Thank you in advance for your time, and for the potential solution.

Comment: use regular methods to post something on facebook, those kind of things (especially "prefilling" and automatic posting) are not allowed.

Comment: This is a regular method. Instead of me sharing something manually on my profile every X hours, I'd like Selenium IDE to do that for me. Just because some things could be used for wrongdoing - that doesn't mean they're not allowed. But thank you for your input.

And let's not forget the question - "How to emulate a Paste in Selenium IDE". I could've decided not to mention FB at all. FYI not only "automatic posting" is allowed, but there's an integrated tool about scheduling automated posting on a Facebook page.

Comment: that is a whole different story when it comes to facebook pages instead of user profiles. for example, you are not allowed to use your personal profile for commercial reasons or to automate posting. for pages, it is no problem - but you can just use the API for it. rule of thumb: if there is no API for it, it is not allowed. but of course, the general question is totally fine, but if you want to ask it in the context of facebook, there is only one correct answer: it is not allowed, so dont do it ;)

Comment: I agree for the API thing, someone somewhere mentioned it few years ago as a rule of thumb as you wrote. Although not allowed != illegal, it may not be suitable for stackoverflow at all. Good point.

Comment: Could you try type a space at the end of the URL or click enter?

Comment: @ApostolosEmmanouilidis Bravo. Do you know why it didn't work for me when I tried space few days ago (among all other things I tried) ? It's because 'space' won't pop the live preview unless the small window for updating the status is brought upfront (you know, when you click in its text field and things around get dimmed). I will contact you tonight on Twitter fellow Manager, so I could send you $10 beer money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a space or enter at the end of the URL.

Comment: As I wrote earlier - Bravo. Do you know why it didn't work for me when I tried space few days ago (among all other things I tried) ? It's because 'space' won't pop the live preview unless the small window for updating the status is brought upfront (you know, when you click in its text field and things around get dimmed). I will contact you tonight on Twitter fellow Manager, so I could send you $10 beer money. (I already did this ,waiting for your reply there)